# IP address when self hosting and using xUnit Test

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, xunit

I have the following function, GetIpAddress in my production code.  I have a xUnit test which calls the website where the function is called.  The function works correctly when running normally but RemoteIpAddress is always null if run from the xUnit test.  Below is my test start up class that is called by the host builder and the Test function is used to send the request.

```
internal static string GetIpAddress(HttpRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        if (request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress != null)
            return request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        DataLink.ProcessError(ex, "Error getting IP address");
        return "error";
    }

    return "unknown";
}


class TestStartup
{
    public TestStartup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ApmCore.Startup.Connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }

    public static HttpClient GetClient()
    {
        var server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<TestStartup>());
        var client = server.CreateClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders
            .Accept
            .Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        return client;
    }

    public static HttpRequestMessage GetRequest(string args, string url)
    {
        return new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new System.Uri(url))
        {
            Content = new StringContent(args, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };
    }
}

[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(TestDataHandler.LogData), MemberType = typeof(TestDataHandler))]
public async Task TestGet(string args, bool expected)
{
    var response = await this._Client.SendAsync(TestStartup.GetRequest(args, "http://localhost/api/Log"));
    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(data, new { success = false });
    Assert.Equal(result.success, expected);
}
```

Comment: This would actually be an integration test instead of a unit test. You should put your client logic into a service layer than can be mocked for testing purposes.

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked. You currently just have a code dump.

Comment: Test server does not open any sockets so there are no IPs. It does everything in memory.

Comment: One option is to run kestrel in process.

Comment: Ok, so if test server does not open sockets and at this point I am still doing unit tests, I guess I should just filter it out until I test it together.  I assumed there was a socket since it was a server instance.  Thanks @Tratcher

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set dummy IP address in integration test with Asp.Net Core TestServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49244283/set-dummy-ip-address-in-integration-test-with-asp-net-core-testserver)

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be a duplicate of [Set dummy IP address in integration test with Asp.Net Core TestServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49244283/set-dummy-ip-address-in-integration-test-with-asp-net-core-testserver)

That question has an answer that could be used to resolve this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49244494/90287

> You can write middleware to set custom IP Address since this property
> is writable:
>
> ```cs
> public class FakeRemoteIpAddressMiddleware
> {
>     private readonly RequestDelegate next;
>     private readonly IPAddress fakeIpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.168.1.32");
>
>     public FakeRemoteIpAddressMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
>     {
>         this.next = next;
>     }
>
>     public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>     {
>         httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress = fakeIpAddress;
>
>         await this.next(httpContext);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Then you can create `StartupStub` class like this:
>
> ```cs
> public class StartupStub : Startup
> {
>     public StartupStub(IConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
>     {
>     }
>
>     public override void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
>     {
>         app.UseMiddleware<FakeRemoteIpAddressMiddleware>();
>         base.Configure(app, env);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> And use it to create a `TestServer`:
>
> ```cs
> new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<StartupStub>());
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just in cases someone else stumbles over this thred.

I solved if with .NET 7 in a Core API application by configuring the app like this:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new() {
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor
});
```

And for the HttpClient I set the XForwardedFor like taht:

```
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Forwarded-For","127.0.0.1");
```

So in the api enpoint the IP could be simply resolved by:

```
var IP = request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress
```